# How to add label's that have values in them

Tags: c#, winforms

This has to do with list boxes, and constants.

First things first, you select each "item" in the list boxes.
Then, using constants, the value would appear in the label's.

```
        workshop = workshopListBox.SelectedItem.ToString();
        switch (workshop)
        {
            case "Outdoor workshop bundle":
                registrationFeeLabel.Text = OUTDOOR_WORKSHOP_BUNDLE.ToString("c");
                break;
            case "Essential Outdoor Field Skills":
                registrationFeeLabel.Text = ESSENTIAL_OUTDOOR_FIELD.ToString("c");
                break;
            case "Picture Perfect Panoramas":
                registrationFeeLabel.Text = PICTURE_PERFECT_PANORAMAS.ToString("c");
                break;
            case "Night Photography Magic":
                registrationFeeLabel.Text = NIGHT_PHOTOGRAPHY_MAGIC.ToString("c");
                break;

        }

        location = locationListBox.SelectedItem.ToString();
        switch (location)
        {
            case "Mont Tremblant":
                lodgingFeeLabel.Text = MONT_TREMBLANT.ToString("c");
                break;
            case "Quebec":
                lodgingFeeLabel.Text = QUEBEC.ToString("c");
                break;
            case "Montreal":
                lodgingFeeLabel.Text = MONTREAL.ToString("c");
                break;
```

here are the constants and values:

> ```
>  const int OUTDOOR_WORKSHOP_BUNDLE = 200;
>     const int ESSENTIAL_OUTDOOR_FIELD = 100;
>     const int PICTURE_PERFECT_PANORAMAS = 100;
>     const int NIGHT_PHOTOGRAPHY_MAGIC = 150;
>     const int MONT_TREMBLANT = 75;
>     const int QUEBEC = 95;
>     const int MONTREAL = 0;
>     string workshop;
>     string location;
> ```

How would I "keep" whatever the value is in the label that the user picks, and add that with the other one that the user picks? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to add the values in the labels, that way lies strange bugs as conversions go awry.

Instead, you already have a way of finding the numeric value for a given ListBox choice, you should use that instead.

Answer (score 0):

You should not perform your business logic in labels and list boxes. I suggest you to create a class for the workshop items

```
public class Workshop
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }

     // Visual Studio 2015 / C#6.0 syntax.
    public override string ToString() => $"{Name} ({Price:c})";
}
```

Now you can create a list with

```
List<Workshop> workshops = new List<Workshop> {
    new Workshop { Name = "Outdoor workshop bundle", Price = 200m },
    new Workshop { Name = "Essential Outdoor Field Skills", Price = 100m},
    ...
};
```

Assign the list to the listbox

```
workshopListBox.DataSource = workshops;
```

Pick the selected item like this

```
var item = (Workshop)workshopListBox.SelectedItem;
```

And add up the price in a sum field

```
decimal sum = 0.0m;  // Make it a field, not a local variable.

...

sum += item.Price;
registrationFeeLabel.Text = sum.ToString("c");
```

Now, because the Workshop item contains name and price and also because the listbox contains Workshop items instead of just strings, you don't need the case statements any more. It is important to override the `ToString` method. The listbox needs it in order to know how to display the items.